# Why do different Lokas have different velocities of time?

Tags: time

For example, time passing for one day of Brahma is not the same as time passing for one day of Pitrs is not the same as time passing for one day of Humans, etc,.

Comment: Bcz they are on different planets.. Science too says that time calculation is different on all planet..even a movie named "Interstellar" plot a story where a man returns from a planet, his daughter on Earth became old but he was still yung...

Comment: @YDS Are you talking about time dilation phenomenon?

Comment: For example, Earth revolves around the Sun in 365.26 days but Jupiter in 11.9 years; Saturn in 29.5 years, Uranus 84 years..it seems that planets hv different velocity of time due to their mass and distance from Sun...

Comment: @YDS now you will trust on movies for science. Movies  mend any unrelated thing to make it interesting. Movies can only stand for entertainment. They can never be relied upon for gaining knowledge.

Comment: In Goloka, abode of Krishna and Radha, one second is equal to one Manvantar on earth.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I didn't say that all movies are fact.. that movie seems to be based on some scientific knowledge..and our scriptures too say that time calculation is different on all planet..

Comment: @YDS yes. I see. And you are right. I have also read few instance of time dilation in Scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

Different lokas reside on different astral planes thus what I think is that they must be having their own star/stars like our Sun.  Thus their time relatively differs from ours.

Just want to mention some interesting things that I have read about lokas in the book Muktananda Wagishwari by saint Muktananda.

> 1. Pitruloka's one day is equivalent to an year of earth. Thus we do Tarpan Vidhi or Shraadh every year in Pitru Paksha.
>
> 2.There is Sidhaloka where all saints and sages live.
>
> 3.Hell is a truth and not a myth. Hell has rather Raurav Narak has rocks of faecal matter and urine etc.
>
> 4.There are many other lokas like Shastras say like Chandraloka, Suryaloka, Satyaloka and shastras are very true.

Astral planes are very different and our human body can not be used to go there, only our astral body can travel various lokas.

Thats all I know.. hope it helped...

Comment: pitru loka's one day equals one month on earth, not one year. that's why they do tarpan every amavasya.

Comment: deva loka's one day equals one year on earth.